# Замена статичного текста на ссылки "опять как вк"

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

В продолжение использования регулярных выражений хочу спросить ещё один момент:

```
$text = "mail.yandex.ru yandex.ru/mail";
preg_replace('#([0-9a-z_^\.-]+\.|)[0-9a-z_^\.-]+\.(ru|org|com|net|cc)+(|\/[0-9a-z_^\.-])#is', '<a href="http://$0">$0</a>', $text);
```

Должно менять mail.yandex.ru на <a href="mail.yandex.ru">mail.yandex.ru</a>, а yandex.ru/mail на <a href="yandex.ru/mail">yandex.ru/mail</a>, но меняется только первый домен "меняется, в смысле вставляется ссылка"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = preg_replace('@(http)?(s)?(://)?(([-\w]+\.)+([^\s]+)+[^,.\s])@', '<a href="http$2://$4" target="_blank">$1$2$3$4</a>', $text);
$text = preg_replace("/(^|[\n ])([\w]*?)((www)\.[^ \,\"\t\n\r<]*)/is", "$1$2<a href=\"http://$3\" target=\"_blank\">$3</a>", $text);
```

Comment: Дело в том, что даже 123.323 распознаётся как домен. Именно поэтому я использовал +\.(ru|org|com|net|cc)

Comment: Измените .